# Generate pretty (indented) JSON with serde

Tags: json, rust, serde

Using the [serde_json](https://github.com/serde-rs/json) crate, I can use

```
::serde_json::to_string(&obj)
```

to serialize an object into a JSON string. The resulting JSON uses compact formatting, like:

```
{"foo":1,"bar":2}
```

But how do I generate pretty/indented JSON? For example, I'd like to get this:

```
{
  "foo": 1,
  "bar": 2
}
```

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The [`serde_json::to_string_pretty`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/fn.to_string_pretty.html) function generates pretty-printed indented JSON.

```
use serde_json::json;

fn main() {
    let obj = json!({"foo":1,"bar":2});
    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string_pretty(&obj).unwrap());
}
```

This approach defaults to 2 spaces of indentation, which happens to be what you asked for in your question. You can customize the indentation by using [`PrettyFormatter::with_indent`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/ser/struct.PrettyFormatter.html).

```
use serde::Serialize;
use serde_json::json;

fn main() {
    let obj = json!({"foo":1,"bar":2});

    let mut buf = Vec::new();
    let formatter = serde_json::ser::PrettyFormatter::with_indent(b"    ");
    let mut ser = serde_json::Serializer::with_formatter(&mut buf, formatter);
    obj.serialize(&mut ser).unwrap();
    println!("{}", String::from_utf8(buf).unwrap());
}
```

Comment: I feel like `formatter::to_string(&obj)` and `formatter::to_writer(w, &obj)` are a missing piece of the API.

Answer (score 28):

Use the [`to_string_pretty`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/fn.to_string_pretty.html) function to get indented JSON:

```
::serde_json::to_string_pretty(&obj)
```

Comment: Is there any way to set indentation? By default it seems 2 spaces.